# Chrome driver not working headlessly with Python and Selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, web, web-scraping

I am new to Selenium programming with Python. The code works fine without the --headless argument, but does not execute at all when I try to run it headlessly. Could someone help me out with it?

**Below is my sample code, I am using Python 3.**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'E:/Python/[FreeTutorials.Us] Udemy - python-master-web-scraping-course-doing-20-real-projects/03 Step  _ Download HTML Content/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.tirerack.com/survey/ValidationServlet?autoYear=2006&autoMake=Porsche&autoModel=911%20Carrera%20S%20Cabriolet&newDesktop=true")
print ("Headless Chrome Initialized")

html_doc=driver.page_source
soup= BeautifulSoup(html_doc,'lxml')

print(soup)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Error seems to be in the path. Change the driver in Python home path (C:\Python34) and change the path in script.

Comment: No Path is correct, i have checked

Answer (score 0):

I have added headless as an arguement instead of option and it worked for me. Give a try.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path='path to your chromedriver')
driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')
```

Note: Always keep your chromedriver in homepath of python i.e. `C:\Python34`.